# react native navigation statusbar background color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying out react native navigation(v2) for my app, and I can't get it to change the background color of my statusbar.

I am able to change the background color of my `topBar`, but that doesn't affect the statusbar background color. In iOS statusbar color automatically takes the same color as the tintcolor given to the top bar, how do I replicate the same here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Statusbar api`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#settranslucent) directly from `react-native` to your *Parent App level Component*

To set the StatusBar to `translucent` you can pass it as a prop as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#translucent) and change the [backgroundColor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#backgroundcolor) according to your needs as

```
<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={'#fff'}/>
```

Comment: that doesn't help since I need to control the statusbar from react-native-navigation, whcih needs the view controller based setting to be YES, while StatusBar(react) needs it to be NO